# How to solve Invalid keystore format?

Tags: android, flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key from store "/Users/husseinawaesha/key.jks": Invalid keystore format

Comment: Did you follow all the signing process for Android?

Comment: I walked step by step as the flutter documents

Comment: either create a new one or the one you have is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please create a key store by this code

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Reference the keystore from the app

Create a file named appdir/android/key.properties that contains a reference to your keystore:

```
storePassword=password from previous step
keyPassword=password from previous step
keyAlias=key
storeFile=location of the key store file, e.g. 
/Users/username/key.jks
```

add this on app level gradile

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
 def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
 keystoreProperties.load(new 
 FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

  signingConfigs {
  release {
    keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
    keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
    storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
     }
       }
     buildTypes {
     release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

This command line statement from the Play Console Help pages will generate an Upload Keystore, you just have to substitute your own alias and supply the path to keytool...

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

However, while it does ask for a Store password, it does not ask for a Key password. If you are like me new to this you may not notice, and later on when you have to input a Key Password you might find yourself scrambling thru notes trying to find where you wrote it down. If you type something like **keypassword** as a guess it will respond with **Invalid keystore format**.

It is better to use the Android Studio process to generate an Upload Keystore rather than this command line statement.

Comment: Used Android Studio to generate and it worked. Shame that the official react native docs are misleading.

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate the key with android studio.

I got the same issue, the keytool on my M1(OpenJDK) generates invalid key.

Comment: I'm on an M1 too, brand new Android Studio, rebooted & the usual suspects. Still no cigar.

Comment: Solved my problem with my answer below

Answer (score 4):

my problem when generate signed APK:

[image: problem]

and my solution:

[image]

Comment: It works for me, I use jdk 1.8 before.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a conflict between Java versions used by Android Studio and Keytool. To solve it, re-create the keystore using Andtroid Studio's JDK.

1. Remove or rename your current keystore (`.jks` file)
2. Check Android Studio's JDK

```
flutter doctor -v
```

It'll be something like

```
Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

3. Navigate to `bin` folder where `java` is located (your path may differ)

```
cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
```

4. Create new keystore:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting the Zulu Java version because apparently it works better with Macbook M1.

Install SdkMan from sdkman.io

Then to switch your Java version:

```
sdk install java 11.0.13-zulu
sdk use java 11.0.13-zulu
```

(You can always use `sdk java list` to see what you have installed & what you can install etc.)

Then the most important part, ensure your Android Studio is using that Java version - go into Preferences (Android Studio > Settings) and search Gradle, then go to where it says "Gradle JDK" & select the right one.

[image: android studio gradle settings]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was using the android studio with the default JDK and when I changed the JDK to a different one and tried to run the app using the terminal it always failed.

Solution:

- navigate to /Users/"username"/.android/
- remove the debug.keystore using "rm -rf debug.keystore"
- run this command to generate new debug.keystore:
  `"keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android
  -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug"`
- navigate back to your app folder and run "./gradlew  build"

Comment: Windows/Mac/Linux?

Comment: sorry forget to mention: Mac

Comment: same problem, but the app was already published, so I can't change keys. Why the heck one cannot change the Java SDK without invalidating the key format, what a mess.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded Java version should always work and not have problems with the keys:

[image: Embedded JDK version]

For some reason this was set to "11" above, it was the same version, but reported problems. In the attempt to find the right version, I got this error reported by OP, though. I think the embedded JDK version is the recommend one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, for me the solution was just to update the java version and then create new keystore from that new version and thankfully the keystore it created was compatible with the build tools version 33.0.2 which I was using to sign apk.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

**Delete and Regenerate Debug Keystore**
The simplest way to resolve this issue is to delete the debug keystore. Android Studio will automatically generate a new one when you build your project again.

1. **Locate the debug keystore.** The path is usually
   *C:\Users\Your_Username.android\debug.keystore* on Windows.
2. **Delete the *debug.keystore* file.**
3. **Rebuild the project** in Android Studio. A new *debug.keystore* should be generated automatically.