# Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

Having a lot of issues with building the release apk in flutter.

[image]

Here is my key.properties

[image]

Here is my Gradle.

[image]

Comment: a similar issue Take a look at the question below. If that doesn't work, try setting storeFile to "storeFile=key.jks" and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128954/12585274

Comment: Still not working for me :(

Comment: Please double-check the path of your key.jks.

Comment: Path is fine. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please read this instruction from a flutter to release android apk : here error is [related to key.jks file. please follow steps carefully](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android)

also watch this video from youtube : [how to release android apk](https://youtu.be/g1fByAsqQRk?t=160)

Comment: I have done all these steps already as you can see in the images.

Comment: delete old key and create new one

Comment: see this post    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663623/mac-os-flutter-build-appbundle-failed-invalid-keystore-format